Rowcolor is not working
I'm writing a longtable in latex with this header:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For row and cell colors
\usepackage{array} % For advanced table formatting
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{multirow} % For multirow functionality
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better table rules
\usepackage{colortbl} % Additional color support for tables (optional)

\begin{document}

%% longtable header starts here %%%%

\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % Increase row height
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}l|p{5cm}cc|p{10cm}c}


\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{SPS.OQT.001}}                                              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{009F97} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ }                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Actual result}}  
%The following 3 commands are used to avoid the creation of a blank horizontal line in the middle of the merged cells
\\
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{019F97}  
\specialrule{6pt}{0pt}{-6pt} 
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\cmidrule{4-5}
\rowcolor[HTML]{019F97} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{No}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Test action}}}}                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Expected result}}}                                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{PASS}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{ FAIL }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009F97}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Remarks or attachment ID}}} \\ \hline

\endfirsthead

\end{document}

This is creating a blank cell on my last column. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!


\rowcolor only colours cells which are there. In that row you're missing the last & and hence that last column isn't coloured.

You're right! It is working now - the last column is properly colored. Thanks a lot for your help!

@SaraSantos If you satisfy with the suggestion, then please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark
